# Move instances along a curve in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I instanced cubes that follow a curve in geometry nodes, so that they fit the geometry of the building. But I want every second row to be offset by half a brick, as bricks tend to be.

Here's my setup.
[image]

I've taken this approach because all my angles are sharp. The base curve is a curve path.

I'm looking for a way to move the bricks along the curve left/right so that every second row offsets and so I can make a good offset to the the first row also, so they look better at the building angles.

For clarification, this is what I want to achieve.
[image]
The ability to move bricks along the original curve path.

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so that we can check it out. tbh i cannot really believe that your node tree produces the result of the image

Comment: I'm not sure that I can upload the .blend file here? But the whole node tree is in the picture. You can easily recreate it by copying every node to a curve object.

Comment: you can open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions to provide a blend file

Comment: I think you should accurately describe what you expect for "ends" of segments and for "small" segments parts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "small" segments. I have a connected curve path. I just wish to offset the bricks along the curve/s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for bricks on a curve:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But all my angles are sharp, and this approach will make all of the bricks rotate a bit. I've added a .blend file for clarity.