# Geometry Nodes Split a Curve at Control Points and Instance Along Each Segment

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances

I'm using Geometry Nodes for some complex manipulations but I'm encountering a challenge with the final part of my workflow.

Here's what I've achieved and where I need help

1. **Splitting and Scaling Curve Segments**: I have successfully managed to split a curve at each control point and apply a scaling parameter to reduce the size of each new curve segment. This part is working as expected.
2. **Issue with Object Instancing**: The challenge arises with the third step - instancing an object along these scaled and separated curve segments. Currently, when I use the 'X_Curve_Deform' node to instance along a curve, the object gets stretched between each segment of the curve, which isn't what I'm aiming for. Instead, I'd like to have a distinct, non-stretched copy of the object at each segment, with a clear space between each instance.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to prevent the objects from stretching across segments and ensure that each instance is a separate, intact copy of the object with space between them? I suspect there’s a specific node or setting that I'm missing.

I've been experimenting with various nodes but haven't found the right solution yet.

[image: Object with before the curve is splited]

[image: Object with separated segments]

EDIT :

Maybe I was not clear enough : The goal is to instanciate a curve with random scale and position to get a fully random wall and then to duplicate it verticaly. Then, instead of getting the same stone at control points, I would like to get a specifif one, designed to be an angle stone. The .blend file of my Geometry Nodes is linked in this edit. And then, instead of realising the instances, my top (but not the most important) goal would be to be able to instance the object to get a light scene.

[image: GeoNodes_Random_Brick_Wall]
[image: X_Curve_Deform]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a very simple problem to me: just convert the curve to mesh, you can then use "Split Edges" node and convert back to curve if you want to have it as separate splines, but also you can easily instance on the middles of the segments by converting edges to points:

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like a similar objective as this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309716/move-instances-along-a-curve-in-geometry-nodes ...

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer ! But maybe I was not clear enough, I have edited my post to give more explanations

Comment: @EtienneSommer I tend to answer titles... I read the posts as an explanation of the title. If the title was "How to build a wall of bricks", I probably would have just linked to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/306122/60486)